# Call shell script from another unix machine

Tags: shell, unix

I have a new requirement, here I have a DEV and ITG Unix machines. Now I need to call DEV machine shell script from ITG machine shell script.

So can anyone tell me how I can do it.

Thanks
Sai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by doing a ssh

```
  SSH_RUN="ssh $USER@$HOST"  // declared a ssh variable to ssh

  $SSH_RUN "bash myscript.sh" // use the varaible to call your script on the dev machine
```